# Searching YouTube using API from PHP with more than one word in search term

Tags: php, api, youtube, zend-gdata

I have been trying to use the YouTube API to search for videos from YouTube using the Zend Gdata class. When I type a search term with a single word I get back expected results but when I start using more than one work in my search term I dont seem to get back very good results, the videos do not seem to be related to my search term.

I urlencode the search term before passing it to youtube - ie

```
$query->videoQuery = urlencode($searchString);
```

Has anyone come across a similar problem? any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how the Youtube API provides search results but you can try the following:

Option 1: (Adds quotes around the query)

```
$query->videoQuery = urlencode('"' . $searchString . '"');
```

Option 2: (Adds a '+' in front of each word)

```
$query->videoQuery = urlencode('+' . preg_replace('/\s+/', ' +', $searchString));
```

Comment: Would it be faster to just do `str_replace(' ',' +', $searchString);`? Also, your query requires that at least two spaces are required to replace them with `+`. Use `'/\s+/'` instead :P.

Comment: Good catch! Yeah the preg_replace should be /\s+/ (answer edited).  The problem with doing a str_replace(' '...) is if someone has a search string with two spaces 'foo  bar' it would become 'foo + +bar'

Comment: Its that simple! thanks Chris, option 1 worked great. FYI when I tried option 2 it didnt return any results but option 1 returned expected videos for my search string. thanks!